# Change chapter name in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, naming

I need to change "Chapter" word to, for example, "Heading".
I tried to use command `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Heading}` but it changed chapter name only in text, but in ToC it's still "Chapter".
How can I change chapter title in ToC too?

Comment: Which document class(es) are you using? And, are you already using a package such as `tocloft`?

Comment: Would you please add a minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this issue was caused by `babel` package (I'm writing text in russian).
Adding following commands solved this problem

```
\addto\captionsrussian{
  \def\chaptername{Heading}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try `\contentsname`, see https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fixnam

And I agree, it sound rather odd that the ToC write the chapter name, so a MWE would be nice.